# Type inference picks the wrong supertrait

Tags: rust, type-inference

This code:

```
trait Foo: PartialOrd + PartialOrd<<Self as Foo>::A> {
    type A;
}

trait Bar {
    type B: Foo;

    fn bar(&self) -> Self::B;
}

fn baz<T: Bar>(x: T, y: T) -> bool {
    x.bar() < y.bar()
}
```

fails to compile with this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:12:15
   |
12 |     x.bar() < y.bar()
   |               ^^^^^^^ expected Foo::A, found Bar::B
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<<T as Bar>::B as Foo>::A`
              found associated type `<T as Bar>::B`
```

which seems to imply that type inference is trying to call the `B: PartialOrd<B::A>` impl instead of the `B: PartialOrd<B>` impl which is also available.

Is this a bug or just an (intentional/unintentional) limitation of Rust's type inference?

Is there a better workaround than this:

```
<T::B as PartialOrd>::partial_cmp(&x.bar(), &y.bar()) == Some(Ordering::Less)
```

Comment: Seems like inference prefers a more specific trait if possible, if that'd be the other way around, it would be as much as confusing as your case

Comment: @AlexLarionov: Well, it could also have _no_ preference, and just pick the one that works ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. looks like it just picks the most right one: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14019e886ebd955fa4ba8f66c6bb8064 ^^

Comment: @ÖmerErden lol now this is amusing

Comment: Also, the `<Self as Foo>::A` isn't necessary, it's just as broken with `PartialOrd<i32>`

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72582

Comment: @ÖmerErden I supposed "type inference picks the *right* supertrait" would also have been an appropriate title for this question ;)

Comment: With the [newly-integrated Chalk solver](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2020/05/18/traits-sprint-2.html#rustc-integration-mvp) (`-Z chalk` flag on 1.44-nightly), this is actually accepted! That's not a guarantee of any kind, but it gives me hope that this is probably being worked on.

Comment: @trentcl Yeah there's a lot of nice things that are going to come with chalk (I'm excited for implied bounds myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug/limitation of Rust that was fixed by https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/73905.  The first Rust release with the fix was 1.49.0.